# Managing own user and workspace database on Cloud9 installed locally

Tags: cloud, cloud9-ide, eclipse-orion

I am new to Cloud9 and I'm having a hard time understanding its constraints when it comes to users and workspaces management.

I have installed Cloud9 locally at Debian and it works OK but I was surprised that I was already "logged in" as John Doe and can't really log in as someone else. For example using my own c9.io account.

What I expected (or rather - what I need) is before I launch Cloud9 server, I setup a database that will contain users and workspaces, which of course integrates with c9 user panel and workspace view. Then anyone who goes into the site is asked to either sign in or sign up. Their accounts are stored in my database, not c9's.

Is it even possible in Cloud9? If not, maybe you know some other cloud based IDEs that allow it? I tried Eclipse Orion and Che, but those didn't meet expectations.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 doesn't have official support for local right now and as such it is not a seamless integration. If you'd like to set a password/user to log into the local instance you can use `-a username:password` but there is no way to have things sync up with your cloud account.

When starting the local Cloud9 instance do:

`node server.js -p 8181 -l 0.0.0.0 -a username:password`

Comment: Thank you. I know about this "-a" option but - like you say - it doesn't do what I need.